# Notation used for differential area, why is $d^2 r$ never used?

Tags: soft-question, notation, differential

We often write $d^3 r$ to denote differential volume element. But I never us writing $d^2 r$. We normally write $dA$ instead. Is there a reason why we don't see $d^2 r$?

I'm just curious as in solid-state physics I would like to write the differential number, $dN$, of allowed wavevectors in 2 dimensional $\vec k$-space as $$dN=\frac{A}{\left(2\pi\right)^2}d^2\vec k$$
I can't write $dA$ above at it is misleading, since it conflicts with the real-space area, $A$.

Comment: It's not as long to just write $dx_1 dx_2$ compared to $dx_1 dx_2 dx_3$ I guess? If you wrote $d^2 \vec{k}$ I would understand the meaning though.

Comment: @Ian Okay, thanks but why do I never see us writing $d^2 r$?

Comment: Well for one thing $d^3 r$ is a notation inherited from the physicists I think, and 2D integration in physics isn't as extremely commonplace as 3D integration is. Honestly though among mathematicians you could even just write $d\vec{k}$ and we'd get it.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the $d$ to powers $d^2$, $d^3$ under an integral sign means higher differences, or higher order differentials, for me, and not higher dimensional measures.

It is true that we don't have  universally accepted designers for area or volume "elements". Therefore we write ${\rm d}A$ or ${\rm dvol}$. On the other hand euclidean Lebesgue measure is standard in ${\mathbb R}^n$. Therefore you could write ${\rm d}(x)$ for the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure in an integral over a domain $A\subset{\mathbb R}^n$, like
$$\int_Af(x)\>{\rm d}(x)\ ,\quad{\rm or}\quad\int_Af({\bf x})\>{\rm d}({\bf x})\ .$$